# Logistic regression error: New levels in categorical column in Test data

Tags: r, error-handling, logistic-regression, prediction, categorical-data

As I was trying to predict using Logistic Regression model in R, I am having the following error:

> Error

[image: Error:]

> pred <- predict(model,newdata=test)
>   Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
>     factor admission_type_id has new levels 8

From my understanding, the testing data of the column "admission_type_id" has new levels compared training data.
I tried looking at the unique values and I see that Train data has all the values of Test data.

> unique(train$admission_type_id)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCsVC.png) 1    3    2    6    5    8     4
>   Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> unique(test$admission_type_id)
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCsVC.png) 6    1    2    3    5    8    
>   Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

It would be of great help if some one can help me understand the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are having different factor levels for one/many of the predictors:

For example, I am using mtcars data. It should also be present in your session.(Read my comments in between codes)

```
mtcars_train <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% c(4,6),] #Consider this as train data
mtcars_train$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars_train$cyl) #Changing cyl to factor, here cyl values are 4 and 6 only, notice there is no 8

mtcars_orig <- mtcars #Taking the entire data which contain cyl values as 4,6 and 8
mtcars_orig$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars_orig$cyl) #Converting to factors, here again we can see that levels(mtcars_orign$cyl) is 4,6 and 8

lm1 <- lm(am ~ mpg + cyl + hp , data=mtcars_train) # Building the model
predict(lm1, newdata=mtcars_orig) #Now if you try to predict you will receive the error of having missing classes

lm1$xlevels[["cyl"]] <- union(lm1$xlevels[["cyl"]], levels(mtcars_orig$cyl)) #You can fix this here by running this code, it will append the levels to your original lm1 model here
```

After running the last step if you run the predict , you will have your outcome.

```
predict(lm1, newdata=mtcars_orig)
```

My suggestion is, take a train sample which is a very good representation of your entire dataset and your train and test should match, if there is a mismatch of factor levels this error will always come.

Comment: Thank you for your response mate.  When I use unique(), I see the same levels in both train & test. So why is this issue occurring?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hitin, please paste your sample of both the data using `dput(head(dataframe,20))` in your question, its hard to determine the reasons without seeing your data.

Comment: @Hitin, I can see a discrepancy , you are missing a 7 from training and 4 from test. It seems you have created the factors before splitting(hence you are able to see levels even though you don't have the actual values, factors are funny that way, unless you recode them, the old level exists), which is not a bad idea but it seems either you have taken bad sample or the records in this classes/segments are very few.